# Is main() a User-Defined Function?

Tags: c++, user-defined-functions, program-entry-point

The programmer *does* define what happens inside `main()`, after all.

So, should it be considered a user-defined function?

Comment: If it is `user-defined function`, then I should be able to call it. So, can you call `main()` yourself in your code ?

Comment: @Mahesh Couldn't the same be said for library functions?

Comment: @Fritschy I never knew that a user can call main and just thought it to be a entry program for program execution. Just tried it - `warning C4717: 'main' : recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow` , Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Fritschy: Of what relevance is the C standard here?

Comment: @Fritschy, @Mahesh: No, you may not call `main`. See 3.6.1 in C++03.

Comment: @Mahesh Where did you call it from?  Of course it will be recursive if you just put the call in `main` or even in a function that `main` calls unless you put an `if` statement somewhere.

Comment: @Fritschy: Evidently not, since you just asserted the opposite. I wonder who upvoted that factual error!

Comment: @Paul Definitely not a homework/interview question for me.  I did do a search, but the results didn't show anything for C++.

Comment: @Maxpm: the same question seems to come up a lot on places like Yahoo Answers - I had always assumed it must be something from an Indian college course or something like that - maybe from one of those dreadful Kanetekar C/C++ books.

Comment: @PaulR: What on earth does India have to do with anything?

Comment: @Tomalak: because all the Indian colleges seem to base their C/C++ courses on the Kanetkar books, and so all the bad material in these books gets propagated from one generation of Indian graduates to the next.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ standard doesn't have the notion of user-defined functions. Instead, it has the notion of **library functions**. main is not a library function. However, the standard also imposes some requirements on its signature, and that it must not be overloaded or declared static or inline. In particular, it must not be **used**, meaning that you cannot call it.

**Edit**: I originally checked the C standard only. I have now checked the C++ standard as well, and it uses "user-defined" in the following contexts: operators, types, conversions, and libraries. It also has user-declared namespaces, user-declared (default and copy) constructors, and user-written default constructors. It does have "user functions" in 27.1.1.

Comment: Good for the C Standard. Now, let's answer the question, which refers to C++.

Comment: [Presume you mean C++.] Or static. There are a bunch of requirements; 3.6.1 in '03 lists them all.

Comment: @DeadMG: I missed that; I have now updated the answer for C++.

Comment: You are not allowed to call `main()`? Where does it say that?

Comment: 3.6.1p3: "The function main shall not be used within a program." It goes on "The linkage (3.5) of main is implementation-defined.
A program that defines main as deleted or that declares main to be inline, static, or constexpr is ill-formed."

Answer (score 2):

Yes- main is a user defined function. The easiest way to think of it would be user-defined, but Standard-declared.

It also has other restrictions, for example, non-recursive. However, on some compilers like MSVC, it's allowed to recurse in main(). I find this rather handy.

Comment: <quote>I find this rather handy.</quote> That's scarry as your code is now non conformant. Thus not really a C++ program.

Comment: My code has way bigger conformity issues than recursing in main. Non-conformity is not something to be afraid of, it's something to be exercised with discretion, just like everything else.

Comment: wtf??? why would you recurse main???

Comment: @VJo Plenty of reasons.  No need to get worked-up about it.

Comment: @Maxpm Can you name one?

Comment: @VJo An alternative to a loop.

Comment: @Maxpm Calling main is not only very bad practice, but also forbidden by the c++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a user defined function, what would it be? Clearly not a kernel or library function? Not sure I understand what you are getting at here...

Answer (score 1):

`main` function is neither a built-in (predefined) nor user-defined function. It is an exception and you must follow requirements related to it which are stated in C++ standard (e.g. about its presence in program, return type and arguments).

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is not a predefined or inbuilt function. It is a user-defined function with a predefined function prototype (also called function signature). The user writes its functionality, but its declaration has certain restrictions.

Comment: The word "template" has a specific meaning in C++, and this isn't it. And please don't use abbreviations like "u" for "you"; they just make things harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

main() is a predefined function from where the code execution starts. If you don't have a main function the program will not run. Hence main is the starting point of the program.

Comment: It is a user defined function with some restrictions on its signature.

Answer (score 0):

`main()` is neither user-defined nor a built-in library function.

On attempting to compile a C program into an executable, the compiler looks for a function called `main` in your list of sources.

Creating a library (either as a shared object or by just giving out the requisite header files) however, has different ramifications.

Just so you know, GCC looks for `main` with either one of the following signatures:

`int main(int, char **);`

OR

`int main();`